# venv has lower version of pip

Tags: python, python-venv

After breaking my python installation several times, I've learned the hard way not to try to upgrade pip inside a virtual env. Now though I'm confused when I try to create a new venv from scratch because the version of pip inside the venv is lower than outside:

```
PS D:\classes\grad\thesis\repos\tensorflow_modelsPS>pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from d:\tools\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

PS D:\classes\grad\thesis\repos\tensorflow_modelsPS>python -m pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from D:\tools\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

PS D:\classes\grad\thesis\repos\tensorflow_modelsPS>python -m venv .test

PS D:\classes\grad\thesis\repos\tensorflow_modelsPS>. .\.test\Scripts\Activate.ps1
PS D:\classes\grad\thesis\repos\tensorflow_modelsPS>pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from d:\classes\grad\thesis\repos\tensorflow_models\.test\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

Why am I getting an earlier version of pip? (I need a feature on the newest version). How do I tell it to use a newer version?

Comment: @OndrejK. Thanks, yeah, definitely a duplicate.